# Press "onclick" js in http request

Tags: go

```html
<img id="img_verify" src="" height="36" width="140" onclick="testing(this);">
```

Is there a way to press this button in go with a http request?

Edit:
After the button is pressed there's a 10 digit number generated with Math.Random and put in the html, I want to get the number

Comment: Normally the Go code runs on the server side, the HTML code and JavaScript is rendered and runs in the browser, at client side. A Go code at server side can't "click" on a client side button, client side interaction / help is needed to achieve that. Please clarify what is it exactly what you want.

Comment: The javascript on click runs js code: Math.random()

Comment: What you're looking for is called browser automation.  the most common example is https://www.selenium.dev/ go libraries exist -   https://maxfin13.medium.com/selenium-in-go-a-beautiful-nightmare-b5d2d0122df1 is an interesting read on the subject

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. Clicking that button runs some Javascript inside the web browser; there's no HTTP request anywhere for you to make. It's *possible* that the `testing()` function ultimately winds up making some request that you could also make from Go, but that's very situational; there's certainly nothing that will do the translation for you.

Comment: This request makes a get to a site that's generated with math.random, I tried generating the same type of number with go but the site isn't valid